# Virtualbox NAT Network port forwarding refuses connection

Tags: networking, ubuntu, ssh, virtualbox, nat

I created a NAT Network in VirtualBox and from the Ubuntu host I am trying to SSH into the Ubuntu server VM, but I get connection refused. The Ubuntu server VM is connected to the NAT Network using port forwarding. I can connect successfully with port forwarding if I set NAT instead of NAT Network in the adapter, but for this assignment I have to use NAT Network.

Can anybody help? I have already spent many hours trying to solve this. I think the problem might be with the Ubuntu host and not with VirtualBox, but still can't figure out the solution.

**Host**: Ubuntu 18.04.1. LTS

**VirtualBox**: 5.2.18_Ubuntu r123745

**Guest**: ubuntu-16.04.5-server-i386

Guest Network Settings:

[image: guest machine network adapter]

NAT Network:

[image: NAT Network settings]

Port Forwarding Rules:

[image: port forwarding rules]

Guest Network Interfaces:

[image: output of ifconfig on guest VM]

Failing SSH connection

```
root@ThinkPad:~# ssh -vvv user@127.0.0.1 -p 1022
OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.1, OpenSSL 1.0.2n  7 Dec 2017
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug2: resolving "127.0.0.1" port 1022
debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to 127.0.0.1 [127.0.0.1] port 1022.
debug1: connect to address 127.0.0.1 port 1022: Connection refused
ssh: connect to host 127.0.0.1 port 1022: Connection refused
```

**Update**

- I have changed the entry port for the forwarding from 1022 to 10001, because with port 1022 forwarding wasn't working with NAT either.
- When I use port 10001 for forwarding, I can see the on the host VirtualBox is actually listening on that port:

```
root@giacomo-ThinkPad:~# netstat -tulpn
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name    
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:10001           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2482/VirtualBox     
tcp        0      0 192.168.122.1:53        0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1489/dnsmasq
```

Instead when using the same forwarding rules with NAT Network, VirtualBox is not listening. So it looks like the problem might be in VirtualBox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was solved by installing VirtualBox 6.0. With it everything port forwarding from localhost:10001 started working also with NAT Network.